# How to combine Scrapy output

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm very new to Scrapy and this is my most complex spider so far.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class CocabotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cocabot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.tallahasseearts.org/event/?keyword&start_date&end_date&date_format=m-d-Y&term=400&event_location&save_lst_list&view']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI' : 'output/cocaoutput.json'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to concert pages
        for href in response.css("div.search-img a::attr(href)"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_concert)

        # follow links to venue pages
        for href in response.css("span.venue-event a::attr(href)"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_venue)

        # follow links to pagination pages
        for href in response.css("li a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_concert(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract_first()

        yield {
            'headliner' : extract_with_css("h1.p-ttl::text"),
            'venue' : extract_with_css("div.locatn div.a-block-ct div b::text"),
            'venue_address' : extract_with_css("div.locatn div.a-block-ct div p::text"),
            'venue_coca_url' : extract_with_css("span.venue-event a::attr(href)"),
            'event_url' : HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(
                "//div[@class='a-block-ct']/p/a[contains(text(), 'Official Website')]/@href")\
                .extract_first(),
            'event_coca_url' : response.request.url,
            'date_time' : extract_with_css("ul.ind-time li::text"),
            'price' : extract_with_css("div.a-block-ct div.apl-internal-content p::text"),
        }

    def parse_venue(self, response):
        yield {
            'venue_website' : HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(
                    "//div[@class='art-social-item']/a[contains(text(), 'Website')]/@href")\
                    .extract_first(),
        }
```

This is getting all the data I want, but the problem is that the venue_website data is in its own dictionaries. Examples:

```
{"date_time": "Jun 18, 2018 at 08:00 am - 05:00 pm  (Mon)", "event_url": "http://www.music.fsu.edu/Quicklinks/Summer-Music-Camps/EXPLORE-OUR-14-CAMPS/Jazz-Ensemble-Camp-for-Middle-School", "venue_coca_url": null, "venue_address": "122 N. Copeland St., Tallahassee, FL 32304", "price": "Registration for camp is now open. You can register online or by mailing in a registration form. Day Camper Price: $311.00 (Includes tuition only. No housing or meals.) Night Camper Price: $501.00 \u2013 (Includes tuition and housing with three meals per day). A $100.00 non-refundable deposit is due at registration. Balance of camp fees are due by June 4.", "venue": "FSU College of Music", "headliner": "Jazz Ensemble Camp for Middle School", "event_coca_url": "https://www.tallahasseearts.org/event/jazz-ensemble-camp-for-middle-school-3/"},
{"venue_website": "http://www.makinglightproductions.org/"},
{"venue_website": "http://www.mfbooks.us/"},
{"venue_website": null},
```

How would I manage to get the venue_website data into my primary parse_concert dictionaries? I've tried playing around with a follow statement in the parse_concert function and with having the parse_venue data return rather than yield, but I'm just not putting it together quite right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways of generating items that require multiple pages in scrapy:

1. Requests chaining.

Since you need multiple requests to generate one item you need to chain them to go in order and carry your data with you:

```
def parse_concert(self, response):
    concert = {'name': 'red hot chilly hotdogs'}
    venue_url = 'http://someplace.com'
    yield Request(venue_url, meta={'item': concert})

def parse_venue(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['venue_name'] = 'someplace'
    yield item 
    # {'name': 'red hot chilly hotdogs', 'venue_name': 'someplace'}
```

2. Post processing combining.

Alternative solution is to yield your two types of items asynchroniously and later combine them by shared id:

```
def parse_concert(self, response):
    concert = {'name': 'red hot chilly hotdogs', 'id': 1}   
    yield concert
    yield Request(venue_url)

def parse_venue(self, response):
    item = {'venue_name': 'someplace', 'id': 1}
    yield item
```

Then combine in with alternative script:

```
import json
with open('output.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

combined = {}
for item in data:
    if item['id'] in combined:
        combined[item['id']].update(item)
    else:
        combined[item['id']] = item

with open('output_combined.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(combined.values()))
```

Comment: Great answer! I did need a callback=self.parse_venue in the scrapy.Request call, but I think I've got it working the way I want now. Thanks a bunch! Posting my revised spider in another answer for value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got working with the help of the answer above:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class CocabotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cocabot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.tallahasseearts.org/event/?keyword&start_date&end_date&date_format=m-d-Y&term=400&event_location&save_lst_list&view']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI' : 'output/cocaoutput.json'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to concert pages
        for href in response.css("div.search-img a::attr(href)"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_concert)

        # follow links to pagination pages
        for href in response.css("li a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)"):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def parse_concert(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).extract_first()

        concert = {
            'headliner' : extract_with_css("h1.p-ttl::text"),
            'venue' : extract_with_css("div.locatn div.a-block-ct div b::text"),
            'venue_address' : extract_with_css("div.locatn div.a-block-ct div p::text"),
            'venue_coca_url' : extract_with_css("span.venue-event a::attr(href)"),
            'event_url' : HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(
                "//div[@class='a-block-ct']/p/a[contains(text(), 'Official Website')]/@href")\
                .extract_first(),
            'event_coca_url' : response.request.url,
            'date_time' : extract_with_css("ul.ind-time li::text"),
            'price' : extract_with_css("div.a-block-ct div.apl-internal-content p::text"),
        }

        venue_coca_url = concert['venue_coca_url']
        if venue_coca_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(venue_coca_url, meta={'item': concert}, callback=self.parse_venue)
        else:
            yield concert

    def parse_venue(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['venue_website'] = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(
                    "//div[@class='art-social-item']/a[contains(text(), 'Website')]/@href")\
                    .extract_first()
        yield item
```